# Initialize array of pointers to NULL with realloc without iteration

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Is it possible to automatically initialize to NULL the pointers inside an array reallocated with `realloc` without iterate over it? I would like to do something like `calloc` but i need te resize an already existent block of memory.

**For example**:

```
#DEFINE N  50
typedef int *pointerToInt;
typedef pointerToInt *pointerToPointer;
int main(){
   pointerToInt p;
   pointerToPointer pp;
   pp = malloc(sizeof(p)*N);
   //Now i want to resize and initialize my resized vector
   pp = realloc(pp, sizeof(p)*(N+10));
}
```

In first approximation I could change the `malloc`to `calloc`, but when I use `realloc` there's nothing that guarantees me initialized pointers.

Is it necessary to iterate over the whole array and set each single pointer to NULL? Or there's a better way using only `calloc`and `realloc`?

Comment: Iterating over the additional part is very close to optimal; C compilers produce quite good machine code from that pattern.  Why would you wish to avoid the iteration? (Obviously, you need to "remember" both the old and the new size, but that would be true even for the alternatives.)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but do you use `p` for something else than `sizeof p`? Why not simply do e.g. `malloc(sizeof *pp * N)`? And note that defining type-aliases of pointer-types (like `pointerToInt`  and `pointerToPointer`) tend to make code harder to understand. Especially with a name such as `pointerToPointer`, *what* is it a pointer to pointer to?

Comment: Because i'm writing a code where i use a lot of array of pointers. Because of a requirement, i have to check if a specific pointer is NULL, if so allocate a specific amount of memory. Once i reach the upperbound of the array (i need more space) i need to realloc and check again for NULL. I wanted to avoid iterations because they would take a lot of time

Comment: More related to your problem, first of all never assign back to the pointer you pass to `realloc`. If `realloc` fails and return a null pointer, then you lose the original pointer (which would still be valid). And instead of iterating yourself, use [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). And even if you allocate a couple of thousand new elements, the time to "clear" those would be almost unmeasurable on a modern multi-GHz machine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes i will use the p pointer for other things, this was just a simple example to make clear what i needed! I can't post the whole code of mine, it's too long and i think it's useless for the purpose of the question

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right, i'll take care of it! I saw an example here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm
I guess it's a bad practice to realloc over the same pointer, am i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: **No**, there is no standard function to reallocate a block of memory and initialize its newly allocated portion to all bits zero.

The solution is either:

- to not require initialization by keeping track of the valid portion of the array. You obviously must have a way to do this, otherwise how would you decide to reallocate the object.
- to initialize the newly allocated portion explicitly.

There are several problems in your code:

- `#DEFINE N = 50` is incorrect, it should just be `#define N 50`
- hiding pointers behind typedefs is bad: it makes the code obscure and error prone. To do it twice is evil.
- you did not include `<stdlib.h>`
- you do not test for `malloc` failure
- you do not initialize the array allocated by `malloc()` either.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 50

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int **pp, **pp1;
    pp = malloc(sizeof(*pp) * N);
    if (pp) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            pp[i] = NULL;
        }
        //Now I want to resize and initialize my resized vector
        pp1 = realloc(pp, sizeof(*pp) * (N + 10));
        if (pp1) { 
            pp = pp1;
            for (i = N; i < N + 10; i++) {
                pp[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
        free(pp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you could write a utility function for your purpose:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *realloc_zero(void *p, size_t size, size_t new_count, size_t count, int *err) {
    void *newp;
    if (p == NULL)
        count = 0;
    newp = realloc(p, size * new_count);
    if (newp == NULL) {
        *err = 1;
        return p;
    } else {
        if (new_count > count) {
            memset((unsigned char*)newp + size * count, 0, size * (new_count - count));
        }
        *err = 0;
        return newp;
    }
}

#define N 50

int main(void) {
    int err;
    int **pp;
    pp = calloc(sizeof(*pp), N);
    ...
    //Now I want to resize and initialize my resized vector
    pp = realloc_zero(pp, sizeof(*pp), N + 10, N, &err);
    if (err) {
        // could not resize
        free(pp);
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    free(pp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that both `calloc` and `realloc_zero` initialize the block to all bits zero, which is not guaranteed by the C Standard to be a proper representation of `NULL`, although most current architectures do represent the null pointer this way.

Comment: My bad for the mistakes. Anyway as I wrote under the example, the idea was to change the malloc into a calloc (having the array initialized), but i found no way to do that with realloc. I also omit checks ecc... in order to make my question as concise as possible. Next time i'll include them!

Comment: Regarding pointers, i'm following what is written on my school book. Is it a bad practice to use typedef for pointers?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio: hiding pointers behind typedefs does not help understanding how pointers work and what is the difference between pointers and arrays. In order to program in C, it is highly recommended to master these concepts. typedefs are very useful for structures and scalar types as well as function types, but using them to hide pointer indirections is widely regarded as error prone and counterproductive.

Comment: Thank you, i'll keep it in mind! The funny part is that my school book always use this type of approach when using pointer, double pointers ecc... Guess it's not written that well...

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio: it is a local school book or a C book from a known publisher?

Comment: The publisher is well known, but the book is only written in italian and sold in italy

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no automatic way. You must iterate and set each uninitialized pointer.